# To show given set is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading Rudin's real and complex analysis. In chapter 1 , page no 12 , I am stuck on one step in problem( before theorem 1.10). I will mention definition of measurable function given by book first. If X is measurable space , Y is topological space and f is mapping of X into Y , then f is said to be measurable provided for every open set V in Y , it's inverse is a measurable set in X.

Step where I am stuck: Given f a complex measurable function on X, then  E={x:f(x)=0} is measurable.

My try (thoughts): As there is no mention of sigma algebra of X at all, I have to use measurable f somehow to deduce result. Now if I show E is inverse image of some open set in complex plane , I am done (by definition of measurable function). Now clearly E is inverse image of origin of complex plane. But question didn't say anything about topology on complex plane. So what to do? ( If I assume discrete topology , will it be fine?). Thanks.

Comment: Assume it is standard topology. Then $\{0\}$ is closed. Because $f$ is measurable function, the preimage of any closed set is measurable (try showing this).

Comment: If $C$ has any Hausdorff topology, then $\{ 0\}$ is closed, hence $Y\setminus \{0\}$ is open, which shows that $E$ is measurable. Note that they probably meant $C$ to have standard topology.

Comment: In this case we're given that $Y = \Bbb C$, so I think it's safe to assume the usual topology on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @ Jacobian got it . Thanks.

Comment: You can also try showing the set is measurable by showing that it is the intersection of two level sets of $f$.